# Nuget push Cannot prompt for input in non-interactive mode

Tags: nuget

I am running this command

```
nuget push Package.1.0.0.0.nupkg -s http://mysource.com/ xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx -ConfigFile ..\..\.nuget\nuget.config
```

I receive this error

```
UserName: Cannot prompt for input in non-interactive mode.
```

I have specified the nuget.config file which has the username and cleartextpassword like this

```
  <packageSources>
    <add key="NuGet official package source" value="http://www.nuget.org/api/v2" />
    <add key="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
    <add key="PackageName" value="http://mysource.com/nuget" />
  </packageSources>

....    

  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <PackageName>
      <add key="Username" value="<username>" />
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="<clearpassword>" />
    </PackageName>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
```

Why doesn't this work? I am running the batch file from within VS2013 the nuget version I am using is, NuGet Version: 2.8.50926.602

Answer (score 2):

The only way I could make this work right now was based on [this post from Robin Osborne](http://robinosborne.co.uk/2014/09/15/nuget-cannot-prompt-for-input-in-non-interactive-mode/).

- I took the source URL (`http://mysource.com/nuget`) and visited it directly using iexplore
- Windows asked me for authentication credentials, I entered them manually and asked Windows to save the password (this will store them in the user's Window Credentials store).
- I then rerun the PS1 script that did the nuget push operation and it didn't complain at all.

Of course, this is not how it's  intended to work, but at least it unblocked me from the same situation you were experiencing. Treat it as a workaround.

Comment: The same trick worked for me. In my case, the NuGet server was configured in Windows IIS and used Windows authentication. 'Saving password' is essential or it won't work as already described here.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this will help but. I had the same error when trying to push to our private Klondike server. We fixed this by using a valid ApiKey rather than modifying the config.

Comment: I'm using a valid ApiKey, but it's still giving me the same error.  Has anyone found a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

This is not for using the nuget.config file but I had the same problem just running the command line PUSH...

Go to your VSTS website and click the Package link. If you have a feed, click the Connect to feed link. If not, the same link/button will be present on the screen. Click Generate NuGet credentials. Copy the command and paste it into VS PM Console window. Then follow instruction #3 on the page and it works inside VS.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible fix ( which worked in my case ) is that the Personal Access Token ( PAS ) of your Visual Studio Team Services account that you use to authenticate has expired. The default is 90 days, but you can also choose for 180 days or 1 year.

In case you don't know where you do this:

- Log in to your visual studio team services
- Hover on your profile icon at the right top of the screen
- Click on 'Security'
- On the left menu click on 'Personal Access Tokens'
- You can click on the description of the expired PAS to view its properties
- On the detail screen change the "Expires in" value & then click 'Save' at the bottom of the screen.